# http server entire thread pool blocked by recv

Tags: sockets, server, httpserver

I made an http server. I used to make a new thread for every connection. Now I'm using a thread pool.

My issue is that all of my threads get blocked by their call to `recv`, because I'm using keep-alive connections. So when new connections are accepted none of the threads handle it.

What's the solution here? Every tutorial seems to close connections instead of keeping them alive, which is very slow. My current solution is to have a thread pool of like 1000 threads, which is very dumb.

Comment: 'Every tutorial seems to close connections instead of keeping them alive' yeah, true:)  Just as every select/epoll example on those sites is an echo server, (so avoiding storing state across reads:).    A classic threadpool is not suited to a large number of independent I/O tasks.

Comment: "select/epoll" is the concept i need to know about, thanks. didn't realize i could do non-blocking calls to `recv`

Comment: An HTTP keep-alive should have a timeout, it needs to give up eventually. After you send a response for a keep-alive connection (you ARE sending a [`Keep-Alive` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive), aren't you?), then wait only up to X time for a new request to arrive on that connection. If no request arrives before the timeout elapsed, close the connection and put the thread back in the pool. If a new connection appears and the pool is empty, create a new thread, or reject the request with a `Busy` response and close the connection.